# What is a word that describes both adding and editing data?

Tags: single-word-requests

Often when making websites, I will create an HTML form object that I will use in two places: once on a page that allows a user to add a new object, and once on a page that allows a user to edit existing objects.

What is a word that describes such a form? It isn't so much a management form, since managing implies that the object is already created. It isn't a creation form, since that implies we are only making new ones.

More generally, it's common to have a workflow capable of adding new data and editing existing data. Is there a common English word or phrase to describe such workflows clearly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In webdev, this is called an **upsert** form-- a portmanteau of insert and update.

Comment: In SQL the term upsert is common as well. But I think it would be unfamiliar to a typical business user. I'd be interested if anyone knows a non-technical equivalent to upsert.

Comment: I've been programming for over 15 years and I've never seen `upsert` be used by a professional. It's either that I haven't come across it or maybe that I've blocked it out of my memory because it's so hideous. My opinion would be to not use this and instead favour simple explicitness.

Comment: I think upsert is more or less specific to databases, it's not something that's found in many other programming contexts. But I doubt you'll get a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

How about **Content Processing** form?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it's comprehensible other than upsert

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to find a word to describe to different actions: creating and editing. What do they have in common that is reasonably unique to this pair? If you can think of something, use that; if not, it is impossible, and you should use a composite name, like "create and edit". But my guess is that you are using a certain function in this form that is used for both actions: can you describe this function, and pick out a descriptive word from that?

Comment: The common action is doing manipulating the data.  So perhaps if we are making widgets, it could be WidgetManipulationForm, WidgetHandlerForm, or WidgetOperationForm.

Comment: @dvcolgan: Well, if that is the only similarity between the two, then your examples sound appropriate.

Comment: I completely agree with this. I'd go with something like `CreateAndEditObjectForm` or just `ObjectForm`.

Answer (score 3):

How about **CRUD** form ?  More info from wikipedia:

> In computer programming, create, read, update and delete (CRUD) are the four basic functions of persistent storage. Sometimes CRUD is expanded with the words retrieve instead of read or destroy instead of delete. It is also sometimes used to describe user interface conventions that facilitate viewing, searching, and changing information; often using computer-based forms and reports. The term was likely first popularized by James Martin in a 1983 book titled "Managing the Data-base Environment"

Answer (score 2):

Simply referring to it as a data-entry form may be a solution that conveys the non-specific nature of the form.

To @Cerberus' point, adding some additional detail specific to what the form is creating or editing would provide additional context for the users:

The *customer records **data-entry*** form has all the fields I need...